# Can "I write of love" be used as a substitute for "I write about love"?

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context

Can I use something like "*I write of love, I write of hate. I write of destiny and fate.*" instead of "*I write about love, I write about hate. I write about destiny and fate.*"? Do they mean the same?

PS: It's not "off", it's "of".

The context is:

> I write of love, I write of hate.
>   I write of destiny and fate.
>   I write of happiness, I write of pain.
>   I write all this in disdain..

Comment: "Write *of* love"?!!  What's the background,  why would you want to write it anyway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [of](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/of) *preposition*
>   **7** indicating the relationship between a verb and an indirect object [ODO]

*Of* can mean *about* if you *write of* something, or *talk of* it:

> “The time has come,” the Walrus said,
>   “To talk of many things:
>   Of shoes—and ships—and sealing-wax—
>   Of cabbages—and kings—
>   And why the sea is boiling hot—
>   And whether pigs have wings.”
>
> [Jabberwocky](http://www.jabberwocky.com/carroll/walrus.html), Lewis Carroll

Comment: Some of LC's characters have non-standard views on usage. Though I think the Walrus's grammar is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you [could](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/write+of), especially in poetry as your example sounds like it.

Comment: Please check my edit...

Comment: Yes, they do mean the same as my link pointed out :)

Answer (score 1):

Among the many meanings of the preposition **[of](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/of)** is this

> about; concerning: *speak to me of love*